# What's the easiest way to select many frames/in-between faces?

Tags: selection-tools, select

I'm trying to select all my in-between faces so I can extrude them. What's the easiest way to select all of them? Currently I'm just using `shift` + `alt` + `left click` to select the loops, but this is extremely tedious because I have tons of them.

[image]

Fully completed selection of what I want to select:
[image]

Original with no selection:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select some of the faces you want to select then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Area* and it will extend the selection to all the faces with the same area. If it doesn't select all the faces you want, increase the *Threshold* value in the *Operator* box.

[image]

Comment: My keyboard battery was dying and you beat me to it by a second!

Comment: You are a living legend, works like a charm, I'll accept this answer when it let's me.

Comment: @Bentley Carpenter ah ah sorry  ;)